# How to list a user's circles using google plus api with postman for testing?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, postman

Can you tell me how to list a user's circles using google plus api with postman for testing? I don't know how to retrieve all circle of a user by api.

Answer (score 1):

At this time you cant do that please refer to

Issue 9: [Feature Request: Read access to the authenticated user's circles and circle membership](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=9&q=circle&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

The closest thing you can do is get circledByCount which is a number of people that have the user circled.